# gridview on select row event

Tags: asp.net, c#-4.0, gridview

How do I do a grdiview on select row event?  On the source page, I added

```
    OnSelectedIndexChanged="grdTanks_OnSelectRow"
```

in the code behind, I put the function

```
        protected void grdTanks_OnSelectRow(Object sender, GridViewCommandEventArgs e)
        {

        }
```

When I try to do it that way, I get No overload for grdTanks_OnSelectRow matches delegate 'System.EventHandler'

If I change the GridViewComandEventArgs to EventArgs, then it won't allow me to do

```
    if (e.CommandName == "Select")
```

anybody know how to do a OnSelectRow event for a gridview?  Thanks

I also added this code:

```
        protected void grdTanks_RowDataBound(Object sender, GridViewRowEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.Row.RowType == DataControlRowType.DataRow)
    {
        if (e.Row.RowIndex != -1)
        {
            e.Row.Attributes["onmouseover"] = "this.style.cursor='hand';this.style.background='#3260a0';;this.style.color='white'";
            if (e.Row.RowIndex % 2 == 1)
            {
                e.Row.Attributes["onmouseout"] = "this.style.textDecoration='none';this.style.background='white';this.style.color='black'";
            }
            else
            {
                e.Row.Attributes["onmouseout"] = "this.style.textDecoration='none';this.style.background='#bEc8bE';this.style.color='black'";
            }

            e.Row.Attributes["onclick"] = ClientScript.GetPostBackClientHyperlink(this.grdTanks, "Select$" + Convert.ToString(DataBinder.Eval(e.Row.DataItem, "CargoTankID")));
        }
    }

}
```

Answer (score 3):

You could try this:

In the page_load, enter

```
grdTanks.SelectedIndexChanged +=
```

and press tab twice. Visual Studio automatically generates the handler for you. The second param would be EventArgs

Comment: didn't know you could do that, that was cool, thanks. The event handler I'm calling gets called, just trying to use code that was in vb in c#, and it's not converting exactly as is, no surprise.

Answer (score 1):

I think you have to change

```
 protected void grdTanks_OnSelectRow(Object sender, GridViewCommandEventArgs e)
```

To

```
 protected void grdTanks_SelectedIndexChanged(Object sender, GridViewCommandEventArgs e)
```

In your code behind

Comment: I can access the function, so that's not the issue.  I put a break point in there and it hits the break point.  I was trying to convert vb code to c#, so I was trying to keep it the same, but now I'm realizing I'll probably have to change it a little

Comment: Are you using gridview or any other control

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure what you want to do in this event handler. You are already handling for select event and I think, no need to check again for `(e.CommandName == "Select").` ([**MSDN**](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.gridview.selectedindexchanged.aspx):*The SelectedIndexChanged event is raised when a row's Select button is clicked*).
The error said no overload for event and you have to use `EventArgs` argument.

```
protected void grdTanks_OnSelectRow(Object sender, EventArgs e)
{ 
   // May be you want like..
   // Get the currently selected row using the SelectedRow property.
   GridViewRow row = YourGridViewID.SelectedRow;

}
```

Comment: I'm actually converting the existing code from vb to c#.  That's how it was in vb, but I'm trying to leave that out now, as I didn't see a reason for it either, the e.CommandName == "Select"

Comment: May be you are using "onrowcommand" or something in vb.net grid. Because whether using c# or vb.net, command args should not be different.

Comment: I fixed it by using OnRowCommand on the source page, on the vb page, it didn't have that, not sure why....